# SQL SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(ColumnA,'|',ColumnB)

Tags: sql, distinct, concatenation

So I have two tables and I want to use a concat on one of the columns in each table.

TableA

```
ColumnA
1                
1                
2
3
4
4
5
```

TableB

```
ColumnX
a
a
b
c
d
d
e
```

And I want to concat these two columns so they end up looking like the below result WITHOUT dublicates

```
Result
1|a
2|b
3|c
4|d
5|e
```

So I have tried to do the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(ColumnA,'|',ColumnB) where tableA.Relation = TableB.Relation
```

But I am still getting dublicates!? Why????

Comment: What is your releation you're joining on?

Comment: Just a column containing an ID

Comment: Are you sure getting duplicates ..? Make sure you are selecting only one column (that `concat()`) and not like `select distinct concat(....) ,some_column from ...`

Answer (score 0):

you could generate the row_numbers by `row_numbers()` function & then `concat` them (SQL Server)

```
;with cte as
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1)) rn FROM <table>
),cte1 as
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1)) rn FROM <table>
)

select DISTINCT CONCAT(c.ColumnA, '|',c1.ColumnX) from cte c
join cte1 c1 on c1.rn = c.rn
```

Comment: OP has something in his predicate `tableA.Relation = TableB.Relation`

Comment: Why the "Row_Number()"? The values I have, has nothing do do with rownumbers, the true end results will look something like this:*

812436562|2016321045

812436562|2016328124

812436562|2016349124

But I simply want to concat to columns from different tables and make sure there is no dublicates in the end result.

Comment: @ShamatixShamatix the above is correct as per data that you have provided or you don't want to go with `row_number()` then edit the question add some more sample data & results

Answer (score 0):

This is similar only without the CTE

```
select distinct A.a + '|' + B.b
from
(select a, Row_Number() over (order by a) as rowNum
from TableA) as A, 
(select b, Row_Number() over (order by b) as rowNum
from TableB) as B 
where A.rowNum = b.rowNum
```

Comment: Why the "Row_Number()"? The values I have, has nothing do do with rownumbers, the true end results will look something like this:*

812436562|2016321045

812436562|2016328124

812436562|2016349124

But I simply want to concat to columns from different tables and make sure there is no dublicates in the end result.